# error file .htaccess 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with installing a php script coupon

if load .htaccess file

error page

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@lefrasibelle.com
>   to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

this is my .htaccess file

Options -Multiviews

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Tell PHP that the mod_rewrite module is ENABLED.
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^(admin) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(cache) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(installer) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(templates) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(ajax) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(plugins) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^(thumbs) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^go\.php - [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^confirm_subscription\.php - [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^rss\.php - [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^sitemaps - [L,QSA]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What could be your problem?

Comment: If you remove lines until it starts working, which line in particular is causing the error?

Comment: a moment I try to clear lines

Comment: SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On

Comment: I've deleted this code and now it seems to work

Comment: That could be because "On" has a special meaning in htaccess files. Try `SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE "On"` instead

Comment: error 500 whit SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE "On"

Answer (score 0):

You say in the comments that the problematic line is `SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On`, taking into account that line and the comment from the first line it seems that you are using code based on this blog post:

[Detecting mod_rewrite using PHP](http://christian.roy.name/blog/detecting-modrewrite-using-php)

Since the blog post explains that the `SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On` is a workaround for versions of PHP *lower than 4.3.2* (the post is from 2009) you should just delete that line because is not needed nowadays, the detection method described there will use instead [apache_get_modules()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-modules.php) for current versions of PHP.

Also note that this line is not needed at all for using `mod_rewrite`, what activates `mod_rewrite` is `RewriteEngine On`.